# "Could not find package with version stability=dev." Using Satis private repo

Tags: composer-php, satis

I have a satis private repo set up on the url http://packages.ex/, which, when I visit it, lists two packages: `example/admin` and `example/codebase`

When I run `composer create-project example/codebase new-site --repository-url=http://packages.ex stability=dev` I get the error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find package example/codebase with version stability=dev.
```

The composer.json inside example/codebase looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "example/codebase",
    "description": "Example codebase.",
    "keywords": ["codebase", "example"],
    "homepage": "http://www.exampple.com",
    "version": "0.1",
    "repositories": [ { "type": "composer", "url": "http://packages.ex/" } ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Example",
            "email": "example@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "ext-mcrypt": "*",
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
        "way/generators": "dev-master",
        "example/admin": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

I don't know why composer can't find the package as when I visit the private repo in a browser it's there, and I'm specifying `'minimum-stability': 'dev'` in composer.json.

Maybe I'm missing something or doing something wrong. Any ideas?

Is there any way to run a command line check to see if composer can access a particular package and what stabilities it has?

Comment: could you solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have an error or typo in your repository-url parameter and composer try to find package on default packagist.org repo.